# How can I start resilio service automatically when I restart Debian VPS?

Tags: linux, debian

I'm a beginner of Debian.

I install resilio service in my Debian VPS by the artical https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924-Installing-Sync-package-on-Linux, it works well.

But resilio service stoped when I restart Debian VPS, I have to input `service resilio-sync start` in command window manually.

How can I start resilio service automatically when I restart Debian VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's described in the [installation instructions](https://help.resilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206178924-Installing-Sync-package-on-Linux#manage-sync) you linked to:

> Enable Sync service automatic startup under **rslsync** user:
> `sudo systemctl enable resilio-sync`

Comment: Thanks!

Someimes, `sudo systemctl enable resilio-sync` maybe fails.

How can I fire `service resilio-sync start` when I restart Debian VPS? maybe just like the file autoexec.bat in DOS.

BTW, I'm a beginner of linux.

Comment: The [`systemctl enable ...`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#enable%20UNIT%E2%80%A6) command should do this and start the service automatically once
it is "enabled". If the service doesn't automatically start, then there's something broken/misconfigured and you can check the status with `systemctl status ...`
and try `systemctl start ...` or `systemctl restart ...` to fire up the service manually. Read the [Debian systemd Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd) for a short introduction.